# Setting white-space as pre doesn't preserve extra white spaces

Tags: html, css

I am using `white-space:pre` css property to preserve the whitespace characters inside the html element value. The browser html dom looks like this,

[image]

But on rendering, `li` element's values get trimmed and two tabular column format that i tried to use has gone bad and it comes as a one single string.

[image]

How to render multiple whitespace characters using css/js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting `white-space="pre"` in the DOM. It belongs in css.

You need something like:

```
li {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

You will also need to be using a mono-spaced font (in non-monospaced fonts, space characters are not as wide as other characters. So although there are the same number of columns, they are not equally wide).

```css
li {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: mono;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor  lorem</li> 
  <li>Lipsum dolor       lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum        lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dor    lorem</li>
</ul>
```

@freefaller has pointed out that this can be done using inline css like this:

```
<ul>
  <li style="white-space: pre;">Lorem ipsum dolor  lorem</li> 
  <li style="white-space: pre;">Lipsum dolor       lorem</li>
  <li style="white-space: pre;">Lorem ipsum        lorem</li>
  <li style="white-space: pre;">Lorem ipsum dor    lorem</li>
</ul>
```

The reason I would not recommend this solution is that if you want to change that, you have to change every line. HTML is for *describing* the content (e.g `header` or `body`) not telling the browser how it should look.

Comment: Or alternatively `<li style="white-space:pre;">`

Comment: @freefaller true but inline css is not what I want to recommend.

Comment: Fair point, but the user has tried to do it inline, so you could at least show them how to do that... and explain why you prefer one over the other

Comment: @freefaller okay, I've succumbed.

Comment: if i am not using `font-family: mono`, the second column values are not aligned... why doesn't white-space alone solve this problem?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar because in non-monospaced fonts, space characters are not as wide as other characters. So although there are the same number of columns, they are not equally wide.